# Pascal about properties of his triangle.

Tags: arithmetic, triangles

> *In every arithmetic triangle, if two cells are contiguous in the same base,
>   the upper is to the lower as the number of cells from the upper to the top
>   of the base is to the number of those from the lower to the bottom
>   inclusive.*

(Pascal called positions in the same vertical column, in Fig. 15.12, “cells
of the same perpendicular rank,” and those in the same horizontal row
“cells of the same parallel rank”; cells in the same upward-sloping
diagonal he called “cells of the same base.”)

[image]

Can someone explain this to me what is he saying.

Comment: To understand this formulation, it would help to know how he wrote down the triangle, apparently the rows are not from left to right. Anyway, this statement is hard to understand. Do you have an example that you can visualize ? And what is meant with "base" here ?

Comment: I'm actually reading a book "a history of mathematics" by boyer and it is from this book, It says arithmetic triangle was known before pascals time but pascal introduced some properties about this triangle and this statement is exactly quoted from the book.

Comment: i just updated the question. please check it

Comment: I MIGHT have understood it. Let us take $20$ and the $15$ above. $\frac{15}{20}=\frac{3}{4}$. From $20$ to the bottom (including the $20$) , we have $4$ cells and from $15$ to the top (including $15$) we have $3$ cells.

Comment: Thanks, Now I get it.